# Call function without scope resolution operator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

If I have a class called `Helpers.php` with a function `someFunction()`, how can I call that function from a different class without the scope resolution operator?

Here's my current class:

```
<?php

class SomeClass
{
    public function helloWorld()
    {
        return Helpers::someFunction();
    }
}
```

I'd like to rather return just `someFunction();`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [global functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Instead of declaring the helper functions in a class, declare them in a plain PHP file and `include` or `require` them in somewhere like your `routes.php` or your `bootstrap/start.php` file since your using Laravel.

Example:

routes.php

```
<?php

include 'helpers.php';
```

helpers.php

```
<?php

function helloWorld()
{
    return 'test';
}
```

In a controller:

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo helloWorld();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare global functions in a file as helper functions, for example, You may create a file as following `app/Helpers/functions.php` and just declare functions like this:

```
<?php

// app/Helpers/Functions.php

someFunction()
{
    // ...
}

SomeAnotherFunction($arg1, $arg2)
{
    // ...
}
```

To use these functions you can call them directly from anywhere like:

```
someFunction();

SomeAnotherFunction('something', 'SomeThingElse');
```

Just make sure to add the entry in your "autoload" section in `composer.json` file like:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/functions.php" // <--- This is required
    ]
},
```